# Can I connect a Lutron Caseta switch to a half hot outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, receptacle

I recently installed a Lutron Caseta (PD-6ans) switch that connects to a half-hot outlet. I noticed there is still a trickle of electricity coming out of the switch even when it's off. Enough to make a non-dimmable LED bulb flash in the lamp plugged into it. I switched to a dimmable LED bulb and that fixed the flash problem, but there's still a trickle going to the half hot side of the outlet when the switch is off. Is that a big no-no? How can I fix it? Or am I worrying about nothing?

Thanks for the help!!

Edit: Here's the entire wiring of everything in question. There were two three-way mechanical switches that controlled two half hot outlets (used for lamps). I replaced one of the mechanical switches with a PD 6ans and wired the other mechanical switch according to how Lutron says to do it. Everything works how I want it to, but still have some current flowing when it should be off.

Comment: When you wired the PD-6ANS into the existing 3-way wiring circuit did you retain the existing mechanical switch at the other end of the switching circuit? If so consider the alternate approach where that other switch is replaced with a Pico remote. Not sure if that would solve your issue or not.

Comment: @MattEvansKC Is the PD-6ANS on the *line* or the *load* side of the 3-way circuit?  Also, does pulling out the service-switch on the Caseta (it's a small tab at the bottom front that is a mechanical load disconnect when pulled out) stop the leakage?

Comment: So this isn't a straight up 1-way switch replacement, you're actually dealing with a 3-way complex.  Typically in 3-way complexes, there are 2 switch locations but only 0 or 1 of them (usually 1) have neutral available.  You can't just say "I pick!" when fitting a smart switch in a 3-way.  The layout of the wiring forces  you to 1 location (or sometimes 0).

Comment: Looking at the model you claimed (PD-6ans), the instructions don't say a word about 3way, they say "go to http://www.casetawireless.com/3way ".  This bounces you to a PDF. **The PDF is for the wrong unit**.  However if you page down, you find it is a monster PDF and you start seeing PDF instructions to other units.  The one starting on page 14 looks relevant to you.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am not sure which side the switch is on, but when I pull out the service tab it does stop the leakage.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I have also tried to replace the mechanical switch with the pico and the leakage still occurs. Harper, both boxes have a neutral wire to them in this circuit.

Comment: @MattEvansKC -- do you have a multimeter or non-contact voltage tester?

Comment: @MattEvansKC - did you follow the instructions on page 7 of this document?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes I have a non-contact voltage tester. How would I determine which side the switch is on?

Comment: @MattEvansKC -- pull the service-tab out on the Caseta, then open up the box with the Caseta in it and see if the wire connected to the Caseta's blue wire is switched by the mechanical switch?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MattEvansKC - did you follow the instructions on page 7 of this document?

http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/369831_ENG.pdf

[image: PD6ans 3-way wiring]

You do need to identify whether the three way you are replacing is on the line side or the load side.

Comment: How would I identify which switch is on the line or load side?